# Modifying values of array during Iteration using JSTL c:forEach

Tags: arrays, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I am trying iterate over an array in a JSP using **c:forEach**. What I want is to convert each array element to lowercase, remove all the white spaces and concatenate **'-wrapper'** at the end of it. I want to use this value as the id of an div.

For example, if an element in array is '**Mobile Devices**', I want the final value to be '**mobiledevices-wrapper**'.

I'm not aware if there are such function like replace() and toLower() in JSTL. How can I modify the below code. Please help.

```
<c:forEach items="${userChargingTypeAccessArray}" var="chargingType">
    <div id="${chargingType.value}"></div>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fn:replace()` and `fn:toLowerCase()`.

```
<c:forEach items="${userChargingTypeAccessArray}" var="chargingType">
    <div id="${fn:toLowerCase(fn:replace(chargingType.value,' ',''))}-wrapper"></div>
</c:forEach>
```